# Expo React-Native crashes when trying to simulate on android

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-emulator, expo

I've created a simple expo project, and have an emulated pixel 4 running through android studio.  When I try to click on the 'Run on android device/emulator' option, from the webpage generated from 'expo start', I get a pop up on the lower right corner with the message 'Error opening simulator, check metro logs for details.'

I've also tried running it from the command line by pressing the 'a' key for the 'open Android' option and get the following message before the local project crashes.

```
Developer tools running on http://localhost:19002
Opening developer tools in the browser...
Starting Metro Bundler

at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:282:19)
at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:477:16)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

I'm guessing there's some step in getting the emulator to work that I either did incorrectly or must have missed.  Running the project app in a browser works fine.

SDK path is declared in ~/.bashrc, adb is running fine, and recognizes the emulated device.

Currently working using Linux.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, you got any solution?